# mvc 4, json jquery autocomplete encryption

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, encryption, jsonresult

I have an MVC 4 controller with a "GetPaged" method that returns a JsonResult.

the GetPaged action is being invoked by a javascript ajax call, as is roughly shown below:

```
var source =
{
    datatype: "json",
    url: 'controller/GetPaged',
}
```

My controller has the [Authorize] attribute.

Will the json result be encrypted by default? and if not, can it be?

Comment: Encryption and authorization are two completely different concepts.  And simple encryption would be useless anyway.  What are you trying to defend against?

Comment: You may want to use SSL.

Comment: I don't want to return clear text json data.

Comment: That almost definitely won't do you any good.  Anyone who can read the data can also read the key you use to decrypt it.

Comment: Encryption is not a magic potion which instantly adds security; it's a tool which can be used to protect against certain threats.  **What are you trying to defend against?**

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Comment: I want to prevent data being transmitted from the web server to the client in "plaintext"

Comment: Just use SSL.  Any other approach will be useless.